# Make an If statement from stuff inside a foreach loop outside the loop?

Tags: php

Im trying to NOT show a specific field inside the loop, so I need to get a list of all the field types so I can use it inside the if statement. Not sure how I can do this properly?

```
foreach($this->sections as $k => $section){

    foreach($section['fields'] as $k => $type){

        //This makes a nice list of all the stuff I need
        echo '<li>'.var_dump ($type['type']).'</li>';
    }     
        //Outside the loop doesn't dump all of the contents just some  
        echo '<li>'.var_dump ($type['type']).'</li>';

    if($type['type'] != 'switch'){

        //My stuff

    }

}
```

The idea is to loop all the field types, except for one specific type declared in the if statement. The for each is so I can get a list of all the field types.

Answer (score 3):

As you might already experienced the construct you propose is not desired since the `if` statement will be executed after the loop has already ended.

---

You can use the `continue` keyword to jump to the next iteration and skip fields you're not interested in.

```
foreach ($section['fields'] as $k => $type) {
    if ($type['type'] != 'switch') {
        continue;
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Yeah I was reading that on php.net.. thinking about it more its starting to make sense... obviously I have never used continue before,  do I need to wrap my main code with that foreach statement? not 100% sure but wont that loop my "//do stuff" for all fields instead of sections (in my code)

Comment: The variable is perfectly fine even outside the loop, if the loop has run at least once and the variable was created. But it only holds the value of the last iteration obviously.

Comment: Where does $fields come from though? Is this just random or is it from `$section['fields']` does fields inside the bracket become a variable? Just to clear myself up I am trying to loop `$this->sections` and pull all the field types from `$this->sections` and exclude a field type from the loop.

Comment: @deceze I wasn't aware of that. Changed the corresponding part to be more accurate.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry It's just a sample to demonstrate `continue`. I will update it to make it suit your scenario.

Comment: Oh ok that helps me, thanks. Usually that helps me learn something new when it matches whatever scenario I am working with thanks.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question at least I dont think. I dont want to wrap my //do stuff with the `$section['fields']` loop but I want to wrap it with an if statement that uses data from the loop so I can limit the loop from certain fields.. the // do stuff loops each `$this->sections`

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry What you're saying doesn't make sense to me. The `if` statement in my answer uses the data and skips unwanted types. That was the requirement I understood from your question.

Comment: Reread the question, there is two foreach statements, the second foreach statement does not have anything. Ill just google it I am sure this is quite common

Comment: I dont mean to sound like a dick, but I found the solution. I did this method but forgot the [] and thats what the missing piece was. Check the OP for my solution.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry No worries. Glad you found a solution to your problem.